# Yodeya.com down?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, site-name

I usually go to Mi Yodeya by going to [yodeya.com](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) (instead of [judaism.stackexchange.com](http://judaism.stackexchange.com)), because it's easier to type quickly, and m.y redirects to j.se. The last time I went to yodeya.com, however, it gave me this message:

```
                                   503 Service Unavailable

                       No server is available to handle this request.
```

Is m.y now permanently down? Or is it a temporary server trouble?

---

[DoubleAA speaking]: As of now [mi.yodeya.com](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) returns the same error as [yodeya.com](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) for me.

Comment: Perhaps something to do with IsaacMoses transferring them to SE?

Comment: @HodofHod My understanding is that an SE staffer was going to be working on the transfer today, in fact. I'll check with him.

Comment: I see this right now. [meta-tag:status-reproduced]

Comment: I just noticed this error a little while ago (7/11/12 late pm) and again just now (7/12/12 early am).

Comment: SE has been notified. Cavalry are coming.

Comment: We're aware of this issue and I'm working with Isaac to get it corrected as quickly as possible.

Comment: Followup question: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1261

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the DNS setting for yodeya.com now and mi.yodeya.com, and now they work (for me, at least). Once SE takes over the yodeya.com domain (in process), they'll have these domains pointed correctly permanently.

Comment: yodeya.com is now working for me, although mi.yodeya still returns a 503

Comment: @HodofHod I just made the same setting for mi.yodeya.com that I did for yodeya.com. Please try it now.

Comment: it's working now, thanks!

Comment: What about miyodeya.com?

Comment: @msh210 That should be working now, too. It does for me (but so did mi.yodeya). Anyone else?

Comment: It is now working for me.

Comment: Followup question: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1261

Answer (score 3):

Just to close the loop, I wanted to report that we've successfully assumed ownership of yodeya.com and miyodeya.com, and both domains appear to be operating properly now.

Comment: http://miyodeya.com takes me to a "not found" page with a panda. "Couldn't find miyodeya.com

The Q&A site miyodeya.com doesn't seem to exist…yet. ..."

Comment: I have the developers checking on this, from all that I can tell it should be working fine, but alas, I also get the "sad panda."

Comment: There apparently was a configuration regression in the system that causes the core q&a engine to "see" that miyodeya belongs to judaism.se.  The devs have corrected it as of this afternoon so it should be working now.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks!